# Метки в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

в ассемблере пока что новичок. Вот возникло пару вопросов.

1. Как идет исполнение программы при встрече метки, допустим идет какие-нибудь команды, затем попадается метка, будет ли заход в нее?
2. Как узнать где конец метки, как это понимает компилятор. Вот есть у меня переход по метке, перешел, а до какого времени будет исполнятся команды, если я хочу за этой меткой разместить какой-то код который не должен быть исполнен при переходе на метку
3. И как вообще правильно размещать метки. Если я хочу в нее попасть только в одном случае, а если не исполняется условие, то не попадать.
4. Покажите пожалуйста пример простенькой программы с меткой и объясните как поэтапно будет выполнятся программа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В результирующем коде меток нет. Нет меток - нет проблем.
2. Никак. Меток то нет. Метки это просто имена для адресов. Не более. То есть, можно было бы использовать непосредственно адреса, но в случае меток, компилятор сделает много работы самостоятельно.

   > а до какого времени будет исполнятся команды

   могут быть такие варианты

   - встретится другая команда перехода
   - выключиться питание
   - команда halt (или ей подобная).
   - то, что не может быть интерпретированно как команда.
3. Меткам побоку, будет ли код возле них исполнятся. Если дойдет очередь - будет. Если нужно, что бы код не исполнялся - воспользуйтесь командой условного/безусловного перехода
4. Ещё раз, метки - это адреса. Можно наставить хоть для каждой строки по метке, от этого процесс исполнения кода не поменяется.

   ```
   jmp test
   add_label:
   add ..
   sub_label:
   sub ..
   test:
   mov ..
   ```

   Вот в этом примере sub и add не будут исполнятся, хотя возле них и есть метки. Но какой то другой код может сделать на них переход.

Какой ассемблер Вы изучаете я не знаю, поэтому код схематический.

Comment: Раз уж у ТС такое непонимание предмета, то я бы еще добавил, что один и тот же адрес может быть помечен любым количеством имен (меток). 

И это никак не повлияет на распределение памяти.

Comment: Я понимаю что это адрес, просто не понимал как компилятор обрабатывает их